# Custom cell with dynamic subviews stack

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView populated by an array of 'Post'. On this tableView I register a class 'PostCell'. This PostCell isn't supported by any nib since I want to dynamically compose it with subviews.

Suppose two subviews, a top yellowView and a bottom redView, each subclass of UIView, are stacked on a PostCell.

My issue is that the below code returns this:

[image]

**ViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  tableView.delegate = self
  tableView.datasource = self
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
  tableView.registerClass(PostCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let post = posts[indexPath.row]
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as! PostCell
  cell.configureForData(post)
  return cell 
}
```

**PostCell**

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  fun configureForData(post: Post){
    let yellowView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 40))
    yellowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    yellowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(yellowView)

    let redView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 40))
    redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(redView)
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 80)
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addConstraint(height)
  }
}
```

**EDIT 1**: This fixes the layout

```
class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

  let yellowView = UIView()
  let redView = UIView()      

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  fun configureForData(post: Post){
    yellowView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    yellowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(yellowView)

    redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(redView)

    layoutIfNeeded
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 80)
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addConstraint(height)

    yellowView.frame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 40))
    redView.frame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 40))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` after `cell.configureForData(post)` in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. But I think it's better to calculate cell height and return it in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` function.

Also you have problem with cell width:

It's because you got `contentView.frame.width` before id correctly laid out. You need to update frames in each layoutSubviews call or use constraints.